Take a map through the tile+ plugin in QGIS to convert it to the WGS 84 coordinate system and split it into mbtiles

this file has CRS - EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator, and I need to get the mbtiles file of a certain area with CRS - EPSG:4326 - WGS 84.

What will you use to read a non-conformant MBTiles tileset?  According to the MBTiles spec, the only CRS that can be used is global-mercator (aka EPSG:3857 or EPSG:41001)
